# Proving that $(\forall\epsilon>0)(\exists n,k\in\mathbb{N})(|\frac{n}{k}-\pi|<\frac{\epsilon}{k})$

Tags: real-analysis

Do you have an elementary proof for:

$$(\forall\epsilon>0)(\exists n,k\in\mathbb{N})(|\frac{n}{k}-\pi|<\frac{\epsilon}{k})$$

---

what is the largest $\delta>1$ such that:

$$(\forall\epsilon>0)(\exists n,k\in\mathbb{N})(|\frac{n}{k}-\pi|<\frac{\epsilon}{k^\delta})$$

Comment: @Chris Eagle: real-analysis usually means measure theory.

Comment: What? No it doesn't.

Comment: Do you mean the *largest* $\delta$ in your second question?

Comment: The question seems to assume implicitly that there exists a largest $\delta$ such that the second statement is true. I feel that the possibility that the second statement is true for all $\delta$ is being excluded.

Comment: let's think supremum is the meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a proof for the first one. Note that $\forall \epsilon>0\,\exists n\in\mathbb{N}\,\exists k\in \mathbb{Z}^+\,\left[\left|\frac{n}{k}-\pi\right|<\frac{\epsilon}{k}\right]$ is equivalent to:
 $$\forall \epsilon>0\,\exists n\in\mathbb{N}\,\exists k\in \mathbb{Z}^+\,[\left|n-k\pi\right|<\epsilon]$$

Let $\epsilon>0$. Let $10^{-r}<\epsilon $ for some $r\in\mathbb{N}$. Now consider the set of numbers $\{k\pi \mid k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$. By the pigeonhole principle, we know that there exist distinct $i,j\in\mathbb{N}$ $(i>j)$ such that $i\pi,j\pi$ have the same first $r$ digits that are on the right of the decimal point. Therefore, $|(i-j)\pi-\lfloor(i-j)\pi\rfloor|<10^{-r}<\epsilon$. Let $n=\lfloor(i-j)\pi)\rfloor$, $k=i-j$  and we get the desired result.

Comment: by $\mathbb{N}$ I mean positive integers.

Comment: I see. I use $\mathbb{N}$ for the set of natural numbers

Comment: I removed $k>0$

Answer (score 1):

For the second question see [mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IrrationalityMeasure.html)